# Read in specific data without FIRSTOBS=

Tags: sas

Is there a way to read in specific parts of my data without using FIRSTOBS=?  For example, I have 5 different files, all of which have a few rows of unwanted characters. I want my data to read in starting with the first row that is numeric. But each of these 5 files have that first numeric row starting in different rows. Rather than going into each file to find where FIRSTOBS should be, is there a way I can instead check this? Perhaps by using an IF statement with ANYDIGIT?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this from the SAS docs? [Example 5: Positioning the Pointer with a Numeric Variable](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146292.htm)

```
data office (drop=x);
    infile file-specification; 
    input x @;
    if 1<=x<=10 then
        input @x City $9.;
    else do;
        put 'Invalid input at line ' _n_;
       delete;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you don't know how many lines are to be skipped at the beginning of each file.  My filerefs are UNIX to run the example on another OS they will need to be changed;

```
*Create two example input data files;
filename FT15F001 '~/file1.txt';
parmcards;
char
char and 103
10 10 10
10 10 10.1
;;;;
   run;
filename FT15F001 '~/file2.txt';
parmcards;
char
char and 103
char
char
char
10 10 10.5
10 10 10
;;;;
   run;
*Read them starting from the first line that has all numbers;
filename FT77F001 '~/file*.txt';
data both;
   infile FT77F001 eov=eov;
   input @;
   /*Reset the flag at the start of each new file*/
   if _n_ eq 1 or eov then do; 
      eov=0;
      flag=1;
      end;
   if flag then do;
      if anyalpha(_infile_) then delete;
      else flag=0;
      end;
   input v1-v3;
   drop flag;
   retain flag;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
INPUT City $@;
  StateAvg = input(substr(City,1,4),COMMA4.);

  IF 5000<= StateAvg <= 7000 THEN
   INPUT City 1-7 State ZIP;
  ELSE DO;
    Delete;
    END;
```

And this worked. Thanks for the suggestions, I went back and looked at example 5 and it helped.